# Error when passing audio file to curl command for Whisper Open AI model

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, flac

Here is my `main.py` file

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from transformers import pipeline

app = Flask(__name__)

# Create a pipeline for automatic speech recognition (ASR)
asr = pipeline("automatic-speech-recognition", model="openai/whisper-large")

@app.route('/recognize', methods=['POST'])
def recognize():
    try:
        # Get the audio file from the request
        audio_file = request.files['audio']

        # Perform automatic speech recognition on the audio
        transcription = asr(audio_file.read())

        # Return the transcription as JSON response
        response = {"transcription": transcription}
        return jsonify(response)

    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"error": str(e)})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

I start my app with `python3 main.py` command.

```
python3 main.py 

 * Serving Flask app 'main'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
 * Running on http://10.16.4.81:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Sep/2023 11:12:53] "POST /recognize HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Sep/2023 11:15:01] "POST /recognize HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Sep/2023 11:15:55] "POST /recognize HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Sep/2023 11:17:48] "POST /recognize HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Sep/2023 11:25:05] "POST /recognize HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Then from another terminal window I ssh to the same server where my app is running and  I try to use curl to pass a flac audio file but I get an error.

```
curl -X POST -F "audio=@/home/ubuntu/speech.flac" http://10.16.4.81:5000/recognize
curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application
```

I tried using a file from internet but got the same output :

```
curl -X POST -F "audio=@https://huggingface.co/datasets/Narsil/asr_dummy/resolve/main/mlk.flac" http://localhost:5000/recognize
curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application
```

Can someone help me to sort this out please ?

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I used an audio file with `.wav` format

```
curl -X POST -F "audio=@/home/ubuntu/audio.wav" http://localhost:5000/recognize
{"transcription":{"text":" I have a dream that one day this nation will rise up and live out the true meaning of its creed."}}
```